# How do I pause/wait a script that is executing?

Tags: c#, windows

I am a `Lua` programmer but I decided to try out `C#`.

I have noticed that it does not have `Wait()` to whom I'm used to. Essentially  I want to apply it for waiting a few seconds or so, and then do the next thing.
How can I do this in `C#`?

Comment: Show the code of the method, edit the question.

Comment: WPF or WinForms? Add proper tag to the question while editing it. And remove `windows` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thread.Sleep` is your guy. [More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: So I have my code. Basically it doesn't seem to listen to the thread.sleep thing? It waits but doens't actually set anything???        `newWindowobj.SetLabelText("hi");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            newWindowobj.SetLabelText(Number.ToString());`

Comment: Seems like there's more to your code than you specified in the question. Would you mind including what your code is trying to do and provide an example as well as what you expect to be the right behaviour? More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Essentially, it's a bingo application. It generates a number and then the number is checked for duplicates before being sent off on a function to another window which displays the current numbers.

Comment: @TheEpicNeonCat Thread.Sleep puts the current thread to sleep which here would be the UI thread. Thus you will never see the effect of the first SetLabelText as the UI thread is sleeping and can’t update the UI. It’s better to declare your method as `async` and use `await Task.Delay(1000);`, which doesn’t block the UI thread, but switches to another thread for 1s, during which the UI thread can update the UI with the first SetLabelText, and then returns to the UI thread to execute the second SetLabelText.

Comment: ckuri is right. I don't know if there's any other catch in your task, do you mind providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?